# Can't select Web Job on Azure

Tags: python, azure, web-applications, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a Web Job on Azure (I have a student account) but the option is greyed out whenever I create a Web App, does anyone know why? I'm aiming to host a Discord bot I wrote on there, although it uses various Python packages and SQLite3 so I'm not sure if it'd even work. If anyone has any other hosting alternatives I'd appreciate suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

WebJob feature is only support in Azure WebApp for Windows, not for Linux on Container.
Also note that Student Subscription will have [`limited services`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0144p/) enabled.